# Questions about p12 certificate and private key password

Tags: certificate, private-key, p12

Currently, I have created a certificate and a private key with a password set to "privateKeyPass".

I then combined the two to create a p12 file and set a password called "keyPass".

And to check whether the private key password of the p12 file was set properly, I checked the p12 file with the following command.

```
openssl pkcs12 -info -in certificate.p12
```

When I entered the password for the p12 file,

the following command appeared and I entered the password "incorrectPassword", which was different from when it was created.

```
Enter PEM pass phrase: incorrectPassword
```

Then, “Verifying - Enter PEM pass phrase:” was displayed,

and when I entered the same password again, the properly encrypted private key came out.

```
Enter PEM pass phrase:incorrectPassword                                                                                                                                                                                                                 Verifying - Enter PEM pass phrase:incorrectPassword
-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
...
-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
```

I have two questions at this time.

1. If the private key password is incorrect, isn't it normal for the private key to not be visible?
2. Is entering the private key password twice a process of resetting the private key password?

I'm asking a question because I can't find the answer.

Comment: This is not about programming or development, thus offtopic, but: when you use `openssl pkcs12` to read a PKCS12 (not create one) it first prompts you with "Enter Import Password" for the password used to create the _input_ PKCS12 file, _then_ twice with "Enter PEM pass phrase" and "Verifying - same" for a password to use to encrypt the _output_ privatekey; this is a new encryption and can be different from the password on the input.